# How do I integrate localStorage to save data (in an array) for current browser session?

Tags: json, reactjs, session, browser, storage

So I have this program written where you can type into a search bar and the options that show up are devices from an API. When you click on a device, it gets added to your "cart", and you can also remove the item by clicking on it while it's in your cart. I know I should use localStorage to get these devices to save for the current browser session, but I've never used localStorage before and I'm not sure how to integrate it into the code I've already written. Any ideas?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: "",
    devices: [],
    bag: []
  };

  addDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
    const array = Array.from(this.state.bag);
    if (array.indexOf(deviceTitle) === -1) { //if item has not already been clicked
      array.push(deviceTitle);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({
      bag: array
    });
  };

  removeDevice = (e, deviceTitle) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      bag: prevState.bag.filter(d => d !== deviceTitle)
    }));
  };

  removeAll = e => {
    this.setState({
      bag: []
    });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      search: value
    });

    this.search(value);
  };

  search = search => {
    const url = `https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/suggest/${search}?doctypes=device`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ devices: data.results });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.search("");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search for devices..."
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          {this.state.devices.map(device => (
            <ul key={device.title}>
              <p>
                {device.title}{" "}
                <i
                  className="fas fa-plus"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "green" }}
                  onClick={e => this.addDevice(e, device.title)}
                />
              </p>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </form>
        {this.state.bag.map(device => (
          <p key={device.title}>
            {device}
            <i
              className="fas fa-times"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "red" }}
              onClick={e => this.removeDevice(e, device)}
            />
          </p>
        ))}
        <button onClick={e => this.removeAll(e)}>Remove all</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you want to achieve. Why do you want to integrate local storage? The only reason I can figure out is to keep the cart after refreshing the page.

Local storage saves data as plain strings so to save an array, You can do that as below

```
const array = {"devices": [{name: 1}, {name: 2}]};
localStorage.setItem('devices', JSON.stringify(array));

// and to get this item
let devicesFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('devices');
devicesFromStorage = JSON.parse(devicesFromStorage).devices;
```

And in your component

```
search = search => {
    const url = `https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/suggest/${search}?doctypes=device`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ devices: data.results });
        localStorage.setItem('devices', JSON.stringify({ devices: data.results }));
      });
  };
```

You can read more about local storage here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

:-) Hi Emily !

Indeed, you can use simple JavaScript Storage Object methods, and more particularly localSession object here.

Methods :

- **setItem**(keyName,yourObject) to store your object in the web browser local storage,
- **getItem**(keyName) to pick up your object from local storage,
- maybe **removeItem**(keyName) if you need to remove your object from the local storage.

Objects must be String objects in the local storage. That's why sarabs3 used JSON.stringify method to convert it to string before storing it.

Hope this helps !